# AJAX message under google ads

Tags: html, css, ads

I'm building a ASP.NET application using C#. On my website, I also use AJAX toolkit from Microsoft. When error message are displayed, they appear under the Google ads.

It's very annoying because before adding the ads, everything was working good. In fact, it work perfectly but I'm searching for a way (probably CSS) to put the error message on top of the ads OR to put the ads from Google in the background.

With all the people having Google ads on their site, I hope someone has found a solution to this problem!

Comment: z-layer? I think Google tries to get on top, so I'm not sure if changing the z-layer will help...

Answer (score 1):

un tested solution.
put your adsense code in a div. add style to you div with z-index:-1. Add z-index:3 or above to your error container. In theory this will make google ads appear under you error message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Google Ads code is specifically designed to make sure it is on top (to prevent "cheating the system" by obscuring or hiding the ads while still displaying them).

Your best bet is probably to try to alter how your error messages are displayed so that they don't go outside of the "content" area of the page into the ad area - perhaps make them appear below the input box instead of to the right of it, or something similar.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea. I would like to try it but I don't know how to change the position of the ajax error without going in the source code of the microsoft toolkit, something I'm not realy comfortable with that..